# 403 - Forbidden: Access Denied on localhost Running From Visual Studio with Sitecore CMS

Tags: .net, visual-studio, localhost, sitecore, access-denied

I am working on a .NET MVC website that uses Sitecore as its CMS system. Recently, I have found that there is a page that I can no longer view when running locally from Visual Studio on my machine. When navigating to this page, I now receive a '403 - Forbidden' error, although I definitely had access to it in the past and can still successfully preview it from the Sitecore CMS website.

I searched online for a solution, but found nothing on 403s received when running locally from Visual Studio. Most similar online posts related to Apache or Wamp servers, so I decided to ask the good folk here at Stack Overflow.

Unfortunately, I am not experienced enough at web development to understand why this can happen. I thought that this kind of error was caused by some permissions issue in IIS, but the page is accessible on the production and staging sites, so the problem only occurs locally. It doesn't seem as though I can make any changes in the IIS Express that Visual Studio uses.

I can confirm that the website has no login, or restricted pages, so this error has nothing to do with incorrect credentials being provided. While I understand that it might be difficult to find a definitive answer to this problem, I'd really appreciate it if you could provide me with some possible causes of this problem that I could investigate further... as of now, I am completely lost.

Please let me know if you need me to provide any further information.

---

EDIT

As requested, please find an image of the
[Security details of the Forbidden Access page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP8OM.png).  At first, it may seem like this is the cause, but I'm pretty sure that security is turned off on the whole site, as NO pages on the site have security access applied. For example, these are [the security details for a page that is accessible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rqg7R.png).

---

EDIT 2

After removing the security for the Anonymous user on the relevant Sitecore page item, the problem still occurs. (Unfortunately, I can't post more than two image links, or upload images because I don't have enough reputation, so you'll just have to take my word that I removed this security.) To re-iterate, there are no roles, or any pages on this website that are restricted to any users.

Comment: Sitecore doesn't work too well with IIS Express. I recommend setting it up to work with IIS and working with your project folder outside the IIS folder: http://timblinetics.azurewebsites.net/how-to-setup-a-visual-studio-project-for-sitecore-outside-of-the-web-root/

Comment: It worked fine before and works fine with all of the other pages. I don't think that this problem is Sitecore related.

Comment: Let me rephrase that... I don't think that IIS Express is causing this problem... Sitecore may well be causing it.

Comment: Can you post the Security details of the item? This may be related to Sitecore security. If the item has broken an inherited read access the anonymous user may no longer be able to view the page.

Comment: @JayS, apologies for the delayed response... I've been away from work for a few days. I have uploaded some security images.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the uploaded security, you have denied access to the anonymous user to read the page. If you access as an end user, you are accessing as the anonymous user. You are receiving the 403 because Sitecore is determining that the user does not have access.

If you look at your 'successful' page security details, you will note that the extranet\anonymous user is not denied read access. As a test, try removing just the extranet\anonymous user from the page you are having an issue with. If you start having access again, that is the source of your issue.

However, you might then need to discover why somebody decided to add that security restriction before permanently removing it. It is possible that it was intended to only be accessed by users in a certain role.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I have followed your advice and updated my question with a further edit, but still the problem remains. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem when I was just running a JSON-server and it worked when I changed the port.